# Rsync , cp or any utility add specific filtered data back from original file to analyzed file

Tags: awk, sed, rsync, cp

I have mistakenly deleted some useful data from my backup file but the problem is I have so far analyzed huge amount of backup file and now i cannot take a another backup and start analyzing from first so can linux community help me on this.
This is file format

```
ORDER ALPHA

Facility: 201  ZZZ        COUNTRY
Wrong Trace:       Kotak: NA       Soak: NA        NOUN: XP

                  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O
                  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O   LAM
AMO ORDER #   P/P R  O  L  H  S  C  N  D  K  M  D  D  C  N   LAM uii ii oo
--- --------  --- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  --- --- -- --

    BZ90rty   K/K AA AA AA NA XP AP NA NA NA NA NA NA AP AP  OOL XP  IP N
a      ZX     A/A WD WD WD NA WD WD NA NA NA NA NA NA WD WD  OOL WD  IP Y
ORDER BURY

Facility: 201  ZZZ        COUNTRY
Wrong Trace:       Kotak: NA       Soak: NA        NOUN: XP

                  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O
                  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O   LAM
AMO ORDER #   P/P R  O  L  H  S  C  N  D  K  M  D  D  C  N   LAM uii ii oo
--- --------  --- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  --- --- -- --

    BZ903901  A/A AA AA AA NA XP AP NA NA NA NA NA NA AP AP  OOL XP  IP N
a      ZX     D/A WD WD WD NA WD WD NA NA NA NA NA NA WD WD  OOL WD  IP Y

ORDER ALUIO
```

I have deleted

```
ORDER ALPHA

Facility: 201  ZZZ        COUNTRY
Wrong Trace:       Kotak: NA       Soak: NA        NOUN: XP

                  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O
                  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O   LAM
AMO ORDER #   P/P R  O  L  H  S  C  N  D  K  M  D  D  C  N   LAM uii ii oo
--- --------  --- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  --- --- -- --

    BZ90rty   D/D AA AA AA NA XP AP NA NA NA NA NA NA AP AP  OOL XP  IP N
a      ZX     D/D WD WD WD NA WD WD NA NA NA NA NA NA WD WD  OOL WD  IP Y
```

like this only ORDER XXXXX number changes but condition remains same
Case 1: (IF NOUN :XP && D/D above D/D) add these data from original file to Backup file.
NOTE:Original file has these Case 1:deleted data ,add these data back to Backupfile(where backup files states mistakenly deleted case 1 data).
Simple flow---->either rsync or cp or sed or awk and append case 1 data from original file to backup file again.

Comment: I have no idea what you want to achieve.

Comment: It is very simple please go through the question,I have deleted some data from file Backup the deleted data is shown above and  i want to copy the type of deleted data back from original file to backup file.(overview)

Answer (score 0):

I did not get, in which form exacly is (a) your original data, (b) your - possibly corrupted - backup data, and (c) did you in any way prepare a file containaning the missing data, that would complete the corrupted backup data.

But here are suggestions:

```
$ cat missing_data corrupted_data > corrected_backup_data
```

or

```
$ diff original_data corrupted_data > missing_data.patch
```

and then

```
$ patch corrupted_data missing_data.patch
```

Regards, Micha